# Javascript function should throw an error if called without arguments or an argument is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling, arguments, undefined

Help! I'm being interviewed on Tuesday, including a test on testdome.com... I looked at some of their "easy" javascript practise questions, and I'm stumped on this one:

Implement the ensure function so that it throws an error if called without arguments or an argument is undefined. Otherwise it should return the given value.

```
function ensure(value) {

}
```

So far, I've got:

```
function ensure(value) {
  if(value){
    return true;
  }
}
```

But how do I check if if the function is called "without arguments or an argument is undefined"?

I've tried a few things, like: else if (typeof value === 'undefined'), but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: `if(value === undefined) throw new Error('message');` covers both cases.

Comment: `typeof value === 'undefined'` should work perfectly. Why do you think it didn't?

Comment: Make sure you took care of ' '. 
if(typeof value === 'undefined')  or  if(value === undefined).

Both will give correct answer.

Comment: @Emissary is right. The content of a variable referencing an argument that is not supplied is always undefined. So simply using the strict equality without the quotes added to undefined will do the trick.

Answer (score 17):

You can check if `value === undefined`, and if so throw an error. Otherwise return the input value.

```js
function ensure(value) {
  if(value === undefined) {
    throw new Error('no arguments');
  }

  return value;
}

console.log(ensure('text'));
console.log(ensure([0,1,2,3]));
console.log(ensure());
```

Comment: So, the `new Error` code is a built in javascript method?  THanks in advance.

Comment: @Gel very much in advance, but yes, you're creating a new instance of the built-in Error class.

Answer (score 6):

```
 function noValueException(value) {
       this.value = value;
       this.name = 'noValueException';
    }

    function ensure(value) {
      if(value === undefined){
          throw new noValueException('No argument passed');       
      }else{ return value;}
    }
```

This will throw an exception to console if no argument is passed to function

Comment: @Emissary sorry thought the question was only for no value passed.. corrected my ans now

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this code it will definitely works

```
function ensure(value) {
    if (value === undefined) {
        throw new error("Undefined")
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
try {
    console.log(ensure("Vikas"));
    console.log(ensure());
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function check(value) {
        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            throw new Error("undefined")
        }
        else {
            return value
        }
    }
    try {
        check()
    }
    catch (ex) {
        throw new Error(ex);
    }
</script>
```